# In a multi-column table, is there a way to change only SOME text in a specific column (and not the entire column) to be bold or italic?

Tags: tables, formatting, multicolumn

Consider the following table. Some of the text in the second column is italic and also the text is broken in order to fit the column width.

[image: This is the table that I am working on.]

When the following code is used, it generates a table where the text can be formatted however the table grows outside the page boundary.

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabularx}{0.7\textwidth}{llll}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{S\#}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Required Input}}   & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Output}} \\ \cline{2-3}
                     & \textbf{1-level}   & \textbf{2-level} &   \\     \hline
```

E-call (EC)                  & Vehicle information, e.g., type and       id,    vehicle location,\ \textit{freight information, e.g., type and amount.}      &     Any output here. \ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}

See picture 2, which is the screenshot of the code:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Environment `tabularx` is already be used, only the usage of the column type `X` is missing. Also it seems the entries should be vertically centered, this can be achieved by the redefinition of `\tabularxcolumn` to internally use column type `m` instead of `p`. Also the example uses the lines of package `booktabs`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{My caption}
  \label{my-label}
  \renewcommand*{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{
    c
    >{\raggedright}X
    >{\raggedright}X
    >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X
  }
    \toprule
    \multirow{2}{*}{\raisebox{-1ex}{\textbf{S\#}}}
    &\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Required Input}}
    & \multirow{2}{\linewidth}{%
      \centering\raisebox{-1ex}{\textbf{Output}}} \\
    \cmidrule{2-3}
    & \textbf{1-level}   & \textbf{2-level} &   \\
    \midrule
    1
    & Vehicle information, e.g., type and id, vehicle location,
      \textit{freight information, e.g., type and amount.}
    &
    & Any output here \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, than you wish something like this:
[image]

From your (not complete code) I made the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{makecell,multirow,tabularx}
    \newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}

    \begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \small
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{cRRR}
\hline
\multirowcell{2}{\thead{S\#}} 
    &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Required Input}}   
        &   \multirowcell{2}{\thead{Output}}    \\ 
    \cline{2-3}
    & \thead{1-level}   & \thead{2-level} &     \\     
    \hline
1   & \itshape
        \textbf{vehicle information},
        eg. type and id,\newline 
        \textbf{freight information},
        eg., type and output
        &               & Any output here       \\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
    \end{document}
```

In preamble I add two packages: `makecell` and `multirow`, redefine `\thead` macro so, that the column heads are in boldface. For some words in table I uase `textbf{...}`.